# Backcoloured text field overlays watermark

Tags: background, jasper-reports, watermark

I'm using *iReports 4.5.1* to develop a report which uses a watermark in the *Background* band.  Some sections of the report have text fields (like column headers) which have a *backcolor* specified.  When the position of the watermark corresponds with these fields, the watermark is completely obscured by the text fields.  When I set **`mode="Transparent"`** on these text fields, the background color disappears completely, which is not desired (and the watermark is visible).

Is there any way to have the two fields overlay each other in typical watermarking style, whilst retaining the background color in the text fields?

[image]

Comment: `Image not attached due to lack of reputation on this site` - You can post the link to a file in external file storage - I'll attach it to your question

Comment: About what Exporter are you talking (pdf, xls, html)?

Comment: Alex K - This displays incorrectly in both the internal iReports viewer and pdf export.  I haven't tried any other formats.  Thanks.

Comment: Image located here - http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/818830/ireport-451-backcoloured-text-field-overlays-watermark

Comment: Thanks Alex for your assistance.

Comment: `Work Orders` - Is it *Group Header* or *Column Header*?

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove the table header from table.
2.To create a another Subreport band for table header. there is using static text to build the table header.